# Can't click link using puppeteer - Thingiverse

Tags: node.js, typescript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate away downloading multiple files on thingiverse. I choose an object at random. But I'm having a hard time locating the link I need, clicking and then downloading. Has someone run into this before can I get some help?

I've tried several other variations.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const response = await page.goto('https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2033856/files');
    const buttons = await page.$x(`//a[contains(text(), 'Download')]`);
    if(buttons.length > 0){
        console.log(buttons.length);
    }  else {
        console.log('no buttons'); 
    }
    await wait(5000);
    await browser.close();
    return 'Finish';
}
async function wait(time: number) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
}

function start() {
    main()
        .then((test) => console.log('DONE'))
        .catch((reason) => console.log('Error: ', reason));
}

start();
```

[Download Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e1Fw.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQNfh.png)

Comment: You are not explaining what the problem is. "But I'm having a hard time locating the link I need" does not tell us what errors you are getting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which link do you need? Clicking and downloading what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work.
The selector is: `a[class^="ThingFile__download"]`

Puppeteer is: `const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');`

Before the `await page.goto()` I always recommend setting the viewport:

```js
await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 720});
```

After that is set, change the `await page.goto()` to have a `waitUntil` option:

```js
const response = await page.goto('https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2033856/files', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // wait until page load
```

Next, this is a very important part. You have to do what is called `waitForSelector()` or `waitForFunction()`.

I added both of these lines of code after the `const response`:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('a[class^="ThingFile__download"]', {visible: true})

await page.waitForFunction("document.querySelector('a[class^=\"ThingFile__download\"]') && document.querySelector('a[class^=\"ThingFile__download\"]').clientHeight != 0");
```

Next, get the `buttons`. For my testing I just grabbed the `button` `href`.

```js
const buttons = await page.$eval('a[class^="ThingFile__download"]', anchor => anchor.getAttribute('href'));
```

Lastly, do not check the `.length` of this variable. In this case we are just returning the `href` value which is a `string`. You will get a `Promise` of an `ElementHandle` when you try getting just the button:

```js
const button = await page.$('a[class^="ThingFile__download"]');
console.log(button)
if (button) { ... }
```

Now if you change that `page.$` to be `page.$$`, you will be getting a `Promise` of an `Array<ElementHandle>`, and will be able to use `.length` there.

```js
const buttonsAll = await page.$$('a[class^="ThingFile__download"]');
console.log(buttonsAll)
if (buttons.length > 0) { ... }
```

##### Hopefully this helps, and if you can't figure it out I can post my full source later if I have time to make it look better.

Comment: Glad to hear that that did. Thanks for the accept and feel free to upvote if you like too!